# Transferring profile settings to other pc

Tags: svn, profile, smartsvn

I'm dealing with quite a few software projects using subversion. Is it somehow possible 
to export the profile settings (project & repository) to transfer it to other PCs?

Comment: Are you trying to move the repository or your working copy? Both?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean when you say "profile settings (project & repository)"?

You can copy everything:

- Repositories: Just copy the directory tree to another computer. Since the URL of the repository changes, you will have to checkout fresh workikng copies or use the "svn switch --relocate" command to relocate the working copies to the new repository location.
- Working copies: Just copy them if you wish. They will function just fine as long as the repository is at the same spot.
- Individual subversion profile settings: Depending on the operating system, these settings live somewhere in your home directory. On a modern windows (since Vista), this is most likely "C:\Users\(your user name)\Application Data\subversion". On a linux/unix machine, it is ~"/.subversion" (most likely /home/(your user name)/.subversion). You can copy these directories to a new computer, too if you want. They can contain passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/), you may simply transfer corresponding files from within SmartSVN's settings directory to your new machine. All of the "Notable configuration files" might be interesting for you:

http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SU/Installation+and+Files